# Cascading Combo Box does not function properly

Tags: asp.net, combobox

I've two combo-box(Countries and States). Combo-box 2 (States) should load associated States with the value selected in the Combo-box 1(Countries).

The problem is, first time selection of a Countries combo-box item, loads the correct associated States in the 2nd combo-box. But when an another value is selected in combo-box 1. The Values inside combo-box still displays old values.

**NOTE:-** On 2nd time NewValues are loaded properly in combo-box 2. But those are not displayed when the the combo-box arrow is click (Only old values are visible). But if we type anything in that 2nd combo-box, New values are displayed.

**QUESTION:- I want evertime the new values are loaded up in 2nd combo-box, it should be displayed on the click of combo-box arrow. Not just after typing something.**

CLASS:-

```
protected void Countries_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int countryIDselected = Convert.ToInt32(Countries.SelectedValue);
    bool AdvanceSearchFlag = true;
    Session["AdvanceSearchFlag"] = AdvanceSearchFlag;
    Session["countryIDselected"] = countryIDselected.ToString();

    int totalStates = States.Items.Count;
    int xyz = totalStates - 1;        if (totalStates != 0)
    {
        while (totalStates > 0)
        {
            States.Items.Remove(totalStates - 1);
            totalStates --;
        }
    }
    States.Items.Clear();
}

protected void States_ItemsRequested(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (StateyLookupInfo state in StateLookupList.GetList(false))
    {
        RadComboBoxItem item = new RadComboBoxItem(State.StateName, State.StateID.ToString());
        comboBox.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

ASPX:-

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Countries" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Countries_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="States" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" OnItemsRequested="States_ItemsRequested" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set EnableLoadOnDemand="false"?

Comment: Yes. That has not made a difference.

Comment: @Kingz What about setting AllowCustomText="false"?